# Explanation needed for round_down macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

In

```
#define ROUND_DOWN(x, s) ((x) & ~((s)-1))
```

i don't quite understand the part `((x) & ~((s)-1))`. I would be very thankful for an explanation.

Comment: It's using a bitmask to chop the lower `log2(s)` bits from `x`.

Comment: I've never seen this macro, it it required that `s` is a power-of-two?

Comment: @MooingDuck, yes, `s` would need to be a power of `2` for the macro to make sense.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: Correct. This effectively rounds down x to the next lower multiple of s

Answer (score 4):

So, a likely usage of this is:

```
ROUND_DOWN(152, 128);
```

Let's look at what happens:

```
~(128 - 1) == ~(127)
           == ~(0x7F)
           == 0xFFFFFF80
```

So, it appears that we are masking out the lower bits of a number.

```
ROUND_DOWN(152, 128) == (152 & 0xFFFFFF80) == 128
ROUND_DOWN(300, 128) == (300 & 0xFFFFFF80) == 256
```

Also, `s` must also be a power of 2. The macro doesn't make much mathematical sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up. ~ means the bitwise **NOT** Thus C = 00001100 and ~C = 11110011 for example.

& is the bitwise **AND** Thus you are anding the value produced by !((s) -1) and the value of (x).

This of course means that the result will have a bit set only when there is a bit set in both values.

For example, keeping it to the lowest 4 bits, consider x = 15 and s = 13.

```
s - 1 = 12 = 0xC - 1100
~(s - 1) = 0011
x & ~(s-1) = 1111 & 0011 = 0011
```

on the other hand if x = 14 you get 1110 & 0011 = 0010